# UIScroll callback in controller or view class

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview, delegates, uiscrollviewdelegate

I have a subclass of `UITableview` (Code below). I have used this class in my view controller. I want the callabck of scroll view in my table class. How can I get the callback in `LargeTitleTableview` class? Or the scroll callback will come only in the controller class? Am I missing any delegate or settings?

```
import Foundation
import UIKit


protocol LargeTitleTableviewDelegate: class {
    func scrollHua(largeTitleTableview: LargeTitleTableview, scrollViewInstance scrollView: UIScrollView)

}
class LargeTitleTableview: UITableView, UITableViewDelegate, UIScrollViewDelegate {
    weak var largeTitleTableviewDelegate: LargeTitleTableviewDelegate?

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        configureTableView()
    }
    fileprivate func configureTableView() {
        self.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 100, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
        self.scrollIndicatorInsets = self.contentInset
        let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: -100, width: 200, height: 100))
        view.backgroundColor = .red
        self.addSubview(view)
        self.delegate = self
    }
    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
            print("Callback is not coming in this class")
            largeTitleTableviewDelegate?.scrollHua(largeTitleTableview: self, scrollViewInstance: scrollView)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have declared

```
class LargeTitleTableview: UITableView, UITableViewDelegate, UIScrollViewDelegate
```

You can delete UIScrollViewDelegate. If this is the table view's delegate, it is the scroll view's delegate; they are the same object and the same delegate.

It is unclear what you think LargeTitleTableviewDelegate would be for. I would just delete it.

It is very odd, however, to make a table view its own delegate. This entire architecture seems like a poor choice. There should be no need to subclass UITableView. If you use a UITableViewController, it is the table view's data source and delegate and you should not try to subvert that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
 1. I have added `UIScrollViewDelegate ` to give it a try because the callback(`scrollViewDidScroll `) is not coming in this class.
2. I subclass UITableView so that all the tables in my project will inherit from this class. All the tables must have some view on the top (requirement). By creating a separate class for table, I can easily achieve by changing the table class in the storyboard.
Real problem is when user scrolls, I need callback in this class `LargeTitleTableview `, so that I can make some modifications according to requirement.